# How to update Lenovo G570 bios in order to install Windows 10 in a GPT disk?

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, lenovo-laptop, gpt

I have used both Win8.1 and Windows 10 before on the same laptop so I know it supports UEFI. However, I can't see the option to enable it under the Boot options menu in my Bios settings. I have tried mbr2gpt tool but UEFI firmware settings don't show up in advanced settings after troubleshooting.
Do I need to flash the BIOS? I have currently installed Win10 on a MBR disk. Are there any cons to having it installed on MBR partition instead of GPT partition?

Comment: “Do I need to flash the BIOS?” - No

Comment: @Ramhound Can you identify what's the possible recourse in this situation?

Comment: What version of Windows did the laptop come with?

Comment: I don't remember. Probably Win7. But as I stated above, I've used Win8.1 and Win10 both for years without any issues related to disk partition types.

Comment: If you want me to provide a possible recourse to your problem, that is the one piece of information, that I must be provided with.  Otherwise, I will be unable to answer this question. Instead of submitting additional comments, edit your question, and provided the required information.  **The laptop will have a COA sticker on it unless you removed it.**